# What to look for when parallelized code runs faster in Visual Studio automated tests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, garbage-collection

We have a C# (.NET 4.0 framework) project with `Parallel.For` loops that runs plenty fast in an automated test inside Visual Studio, but the same parallelized code doesn't run as expected in a standalone application, and we're trying to figure out why.

The code is high-memory usage, but our workstations (Windows 7 PCs) have plenty of RAM so I don't expect any memory paging problems.  No file I/O or GUI code occurs within the parallelized loops.

In the standalone version, the code runs on multiple threads and cores but seems to be throttled to no more than a total of 1 CPU worth of CPU time, despite branching out onto multiple cores.  So, if the code were to use 100% of 1 CPU sequentially, it appears that it would use 25% total over 4 CPUs.

The automated test that runs the code from inside Visual Studio doesn't have this limitation.  The console app appears throttled while the automated test does not.

I've compared `Thread` and `ProcessThread` settings between each, and they appear to be equivalent. They use the same `SynchronizationContext` (null) and `TaskScheduler` (Default).

I've also tried replacing the `Parallel.For` with manually created `Thread`s, and that didn't seem to change anything.

What should I be looking for that could be causing this discrepancy between the automated test in Visual Studio and the standalone application?

Here is some relevant sample code:

```
public void Process(string name)
{
    //...

    Results bestResult = null;
    int best = int.MaxValue;
    Object lockObject = new Object();

    var parent = new Data(this.nameToPart[name]);
    var myParams = new Params(this.params);

    Parallel.For(0, myParams.numRunsPerLvl, (i) =>
    {
        var result = Processor.MultilevelProcessor(parent, myParams);

        if (part.cost < bestCut)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (part.cost < best)
                {
                    best = part.cost;
                    bestResult = result;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: SynchronizationContext? Showing small relevant sample code may help... (and adding info on framework your hosting app using would be useful too).

Comment: " workstations have plenty of RAM" , are they NUMA architecture?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null for both the test and the console app.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, this is just a normal Windows 7 PC with a lot of RAM.  I'll add that to the question text.

Comment: What about `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, is it the same for your app and for your unit tests?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I just discovered that my workstation *does* utilize a NUMA architecture, does that help anything?

Comment: @Noseratio, Is64BitProcess returns true for bath app and unit test.

Comment: @ski maybe some thread accesing another cpu 's data domain which slows access.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Is there some way to test your hypothesis on the cpu's data domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to our problem.  Setting up an App.config file with [gcServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20gcServer) set to true solved our problem. Our application is so instantiation heavy that the garbage collector was killing performance. I guess Visual Studio works its garbage collector differently when running unit tests? In the future we'll also work on minimizing GC use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the TaskScheduler is different?
Try checking the **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.Current** property (from within the task context).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention in the original post, both the test and the console app use the default TaskScheduler.